Does the Poincaré dual commute with pullback and pushforward?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be closed, oriented $n$-dimensional manifolds, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism. For $0 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, consider the composition of the following maps, all of which are isomorphisms: First, the Poincaré duality map from $H_k(Y;\mathbb{R})$ to $H^{n-k}(Y;\mathbb{R})$. Then, the pullback on cohomology from $H^{n-k}(Y;\mathbb{R})$ to $H^{n-k}(X;\mathbb{R})$. And finally, the Poincaré duality map again from $H^{n-k}(X;\mathbb{R})$ to $H_{k}(X;\mathbb{R})$. This composition gives a map from $H_k(Y;\mathbb{R})$ to $H_k(X;\mathbb{R})$. Is this the same map as the pushforward map on homology induced by $f^{-1}: Y \to X$?
The main difficulty lies in the fact that while the Poincaré dual map $PD: H^k \to H_{n-k}$ is explicitly defined by capping with the fundamental class, there is, to the best of my knowledge, no explicit form for the inverse. Any insight would be appreciated.

Sure, just do the analogous contraction of the fundamental cohomology class against the homology class.

The answer is "yes" if $f$ is orientation-preserving and "yes, up to a sign of $-1$" if $f$ is orientation-reversing. Indeed, if $[X]\in H_n(X)$ and $[Y]\in H_n(Y)$ (I suppress the coefficients; any will work as long as PD holds) are the respective fundamental classes, then $f_{\ast}[X]=\pm[Y]$ depending on whether $f$ preserves or reverses orientation. Now, take a homology class $\alpha\in H_k(Y)$. The inverse PD map takes this to a cohomology class $\varphi\in H^{n-k}(Y)$ s.t. $\varphi\cap[Y]=\alpha$, then $f^{\ast}$ takes this to the cohomology class $f^{\ast}\varphi$ and PD takes this to the homology class $f^{\ast}\varphi\cap[X]$ in $H_k(X)$. Now, it remains to use the push-pull formula and compute
$$f^{\ast}\varphi\cap[X]=(f^{-1})_{\ast}f_{\ast}(f^{\ast}\varphi\cap[X])=(f^{-1})_{\ast}(\varphi\cap f_{\ast}[X])=\pm(f^{-1})_{\ast}(\varphi\cap[Y])=\pm(f^{-1})_{\ast}\alpha.$$
